# search database table record using two parameters in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have table call `Product` in that table I have following columns

- Product_ID
- Field_ID

I want to find specific record using  `Product_ID` and `Field_ID` So for that I wrote following code segment

```
    if ((db.Product.Where(u => u.Product_ID == Product_ID))&(db.Product.Where(u => u.Field_ID == FieldID)))
     {
        // code here  
     }
```

But I'm getting

following error

> Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'IQueryable' and 'bool'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exception message is self explanatory. Please check the documentation of [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) (it returns IEnumerable\ IQuerable but you have written this expression inside `if` which expects a Boolean expression, thus the error.)

You should use [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) instead to check for existence of `Product_ID` or `Field_ID`:-

```
db.Product.Any(u => u.Product_ID == Product_ID && u.Field_ID == FieldID)
```

Comment: then getting following error  `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<project_name.Models.Product>' to 'bool'`

Comment: @kez - Yeah you need to use `Any` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&&` in Linq to add another filter condition, so the query will be like the following;

```
 var LinqResult= db.Product.Where(u => u.Product_ID == Product_ID && u.Field_ID == FieldID)
 if( !LinqResult.Any() ) // Check for result contains values or not
   { 
      // your code
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var data = db.Product.Where(x => x.Product_ID == Product_ID && x.Field_ID == FieldID).ToList();
if(data.Count() > 0)
{
//Your code
}
```